# Get Products from attributes label or value(drop down)

Tags: product-list, dropdown-attribute

I am geting all dropdown attributes value and name using below code

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');  

 $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
     ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
     ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer');

 $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());  

 $manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

 foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer){


     echo $manufacturer_name = $manufacturer['label'];
    echo $manufacturer_value = $manufacturer['value'];



 }
```

i am also now how to get product from attributes for this i code this

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');


foreach($collection as $product){
    echo "<pre>";
 print_r($product->getData());
}
```

But My question is that I am create brand slider using manufacturer attributes (dropdown)
and i am set image from using manufacturer label.

But i want to create when click on manufacturer label(xyz) this it will display all product where set (xyz) in product list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => 'xyz'))
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: I am set this code but no result found.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value

Comment: Are you using the value (manufacture name) or the id (magento id)?

Comment: i am trying with manufacture name and i also try with manufacture id

Comment: yes it's working my mistake it's not working thanks